# What was the significance of the scene where the three officers eat together at the end of White Tiger?

Tags: plot-explanation, white-tiger

At the end of the movie [*White Tiger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Tiger_(2012_film)) (2012), there is a scene depicting three officers eating together after the fall of Berlin.

One officer is clearly enjoying the meal and comments that the food is of a high quality, and that it most likely comes from an expensive restaurant. He seems to know the restaurant well as he names it.

The second officer eats the meal and recognizes that it is of a high quality but seems extremely uncomfortable with the experience, especially when dessert is served. He act as if he suspects that this is some kind of trap, and that if he says the wrong thing it will go badly for him.

A third officer observes the exchange between the other two but says nothing. The way that he observes them makes it seem that something important has just happened. As if he was observing the other two to gauge their reactions.

Absolutely nothing comes of this scene. It just ends and is never mentioned again.

Is there any greater significance to this scene, for example from a historical perspective, or is it simply one officer feeling uncomfortable while eating an expensive meal?

Comment: I believed that those were German officers.